# Запятая в обороте "не то(,) что"

Tags: пунктуация

Я постоянно перестраховываюсь и в итоге ставлю больше запятых, чем нужно. Один из трудных для меня случаев — это оборот "не то(,) что". Например: "Он не то(,) что таблицы умножения не знает, он не представляет себе, что это такое".
Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Находите грамматическую основу. *"Он"* — подлежащее, *"не знает"* — сказуемое. Следовательно, это одно предложение, и его не надо разрывать на два. Кстати, между подлежащим и сказуемым не может стоять запятая (одна — не может, две уже могут выделять какой-нибудь обособленный оборот или вводное).